# Prove Glivenko-Cantelli (GC) by bracketing

Tags: empirical-processes

**Question**: My question about the theorem Glivenko-Cantelli (GC) by bracketing is: if $N_{[]}(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},L_{1}(P))=\infty$,
**which part of the above proof will fail**, thus GC will fail.

**Source**: the theorem and the proof are directly from: Bodhisattva Sen, A Gentle Introduction to Empirical Process Theory and Applications, July 19, 2022, Subsection 3.1 GC by bracketing.

**Theorem**:
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a class of measurable functions such that $N_{[]}(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},L_{1}(P))<\infty$
for every $\varepsilon$ > 0. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is Glivenko-Cantelli.

**Proof**:
Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose finitely many $\epsilon$-brackets $[l_{i},u_{i}]$
whose union contains $\mathcal{F}$ and such that $P(u_{i}-l_{i})<\epsilon$,
for every $i$. Then, for every $f\in\mathcal{F}$, there is a bracket
$i$ such that
\begin{equation}
(P_{n}-P)f=P_{n}f-Pf
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=P_{n}f-Pu_{i}+Pu_{i}-Pf
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\leq P_{n}u_{i}-Pu_{i}+Pu_{i}-Pf
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\leq\left(P_{n}-P\right)u_{i}+\epsilon
\end{equation}
Consequently

\begin{equation}
\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}(P_{n}-P)f\leq\max_{i}\left(P_{n}-P\right)u_{i}+\epsilon
\end{equation}

Following the strong law of large numbers
\begin{equation}
\left(P_{n}-P\right)u_{i}\to^{as}0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\max_{i}\left(P_{n}-P\right)u_{i}\to^{as}0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\max_{i}\left(P_{n}-P\right)u_{i}+\epsilon\to^{as}\epsilon
\end{equation}
Thus $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}(P_{n}-P)f$ is bounded above by $\epsilon$
almost surely.

A similar argument also yields

\begin{equation}
(P_{n}-P)f=P_{n}f-Pf=P_{n}f-Pl_{i}+Pl_{i}-Pf
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\geq P_{n}l_{i}-Pl_{i}+Pl_{i}-Pf
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\geq\left(P_{n}-P\right)u_{i}-\epsilon
\end{equation}

Consequently

\begin{equation}
\inf_{f\in\mathcal{F}}(P_{n}-P)f\geq\min_{i}\left(P_{n}-P\right)l_{i}-\epsilon
\end{equation}
Following the strong law of large numbers
\begin{equation}
\min_{i}\left(P_{n}-P\right)l_{i}-\epsilon\to^{as}-\epsilon
\end{equation}
Thus $\inf_{f\in\mathcal{F}}(P_{n}-P)f$ is bounded below by $-\epsilon$
almost surely.

Thus we have
\begin{equation}
\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\left|(P_{n}-P)f\right|=\max\left\{ \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}(P_{n}-P)f,-\inf_{f\in\mathcal{F}}(P_{n}-P)f\right\} 
\end{equation}
Thus we
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\left|(P_{n}-P)f\right|\leq\epsilon,\text{almost surely},\forall\epsilon>0
\end{equation}

As $\epsilon\downarrow0$, we have $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\left|(P_{n}-P)f\right|=\|P_{n}-P\|_{\mathcal{F}}\to0$
almost surely.

**Note**: $P_nf=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i)$, $Pf=Ef(X)$

Comment: The LLN fails if the max is not over finitely many elements because the max of infinitely many elements is not necessarily continuous. The continuous mapping theorem could then not be applied to the max after using the LLN on each element

Comment: Got it. Thank Galton.